# Adding constraint when using group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to list how many times a specific `perNr` appears in the tabel, but I am only interested in those where `count(perNr) > 2`

How can I express this? My current code, that gives me a list without the constraint I want, looks like this.

```
select TREATMENT_TYPE, perNr, count(perNr)
from Treatments
group by perNr, TREATMENT_TYPE;
```

I tried adding the constraint like this (And this gives an error)

```
select TREATMENT_TYPE, perNr, count(perNr)
from Treatments
group by perNr, TREATMENT_TYPE
where count(perNr) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `having` clause.

```
select TREATMENT_TYPE, perNr, count(perNr)
from Treatments
group by perNr, TREATMENT_TYPE
having count(perNr) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` clause will work with non-aggregated data, while `HAVING` clause will work with aggregate data such `GROUP BY` or aggregation function (`MIN/MAX`,`SUM`).

So, you want `HAVING` clause because you are aggregating data based on `perNr, TREATMENT_TYPE` :

```
SELECT perNr, TREATMENT_TYPE, COUNT(perNr)
FROM Treatments
GROUP BY perNr, TREATMENT_TYPE
HAVING COUNT(perNr) > 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

use **Having** instead of **where**

The **HAVING** clause was added to SQL because the **WHERE** keyword could not be used with **aggregate** functions.

```
select TREATMENT_TYPE, perNr, count(perNr)
from Treatments
group by perNr, TREATMENT_TYPE
HAVING count(perNr) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

======================

## You should have use `Having` clause for your requirement.

```
SELECT TREATMENT_TYPE, PERNR, COUNT(PERNR) PERNR_COUNT FROM TREATMENTS GROUP BY PERNR, TREATMENT_TYPE WHERE COUNT(1) > 1
```

---

### Refer below link-

[https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp][1]https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp